# I am looking for a smart way to check the object parameter passed to a function

Tags: javascript

I am in the following situation:

I have to check if the object parameter passed to a function is valid:

Exmaple:

```
function (opt) {
     if (opt && opt.key && opt.key2) {
         // make something
     }
}
```

Is there a better way to make this kind of check?

Comment: *better* in what way? The idea of *better* is subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is valid, but it does have flaws.

```
if (opt && opt.key && opt.key2) {
```

This check would fail if `opt.key` has *falsely* values [0,null,false,and so on]

In that case you would have to do a typeof check to make sure it is not undefined.

```
if (opt && typeof opt.key !== "undefined" && opt.key2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

Unless you can use `opt.pleaseReadMyMind()` ;-)

You could create a method that will check if all fields have values different to `null`, though.

Comment: Is there some sort of feature like reflection in Javascript, that could do this?

Comment: Reflection can be achieved like so: `for (var method in this) {
if (typeof this[method] == 'function') { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

That's the most compact way of doing it.

The most correct way would be:

```
if( typeof opt !== "undefined" && typeof opt.key !== "undefined" && typeof opt.key2 !== "undefined") {
```

But as you can see that's quite a mouthful and not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple test routine to verify the object given a list of property names:

```
// usage: testProps(object to test, [list, of, property, names])
// returns true if object contains all properties
function testProps(obj, props)
{
  if (obj === null)
    return false;

  var i;
  for (i=0; i<props.length; ++i) 
  {
    if (!(props[i] in obj)) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then in your function:

```
if (!testProps(obj, ['key', 'key2'])
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but it's only "better" if you have a lot of keys to check, not just three. Something like this:

```
function opt(opt) {
    for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        if(typeof opt["key"+((i > 0) ? "" : i + 1))] === "undefined") {
            return;
        }
    }

    // create object
}
```

If `opt` is undefined all its keys will be too, so there's an implicit check for that as well.

You could also define the variable names you want to check in array, something like this:

```
var propsToCheck = ["key", "key1", "key2"];

function(opt) {
    for(var i = 0, ii = propsToCheck.length; i<ii; i++) {
        if(typeof opt[propsToCheck[i]] === "undefined") {
            return;
        }

        // create object
    }
}
```

Not really much of a better solution, but it does allow for less typing if you're planning on checking more than three or four properties.

Comment: What? I doubt that the attributes are actually named `key1`, `key2`, `key3` and so on..

Comment: @NiklasB.: You're probably right but I wanted to give the OP something other than a flat out "it's impossible".

Comment: Then you should suggest a method that actually lets one define the name of the attributes in an array or something. That's only my personal opinion, of course.

Comment: @NiklasB. Of course, I actually edited my answer before I saw your comment. :-)

Comment: Why not just a `for (var key in opt) { if (opt.hasOwnProperty(key) {...} }` I can't see a requirement that only special attributes should be checked

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it like this:

```
function validate(o, args) {
    if (typeof(o) == 'object' && args instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (typeof(o[args[i]]) === 'undefined') return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function myFunction(obj) {
    if (validate(obj, ['foo', 'bar'])) {
        // Your code goes here.
    } else {
        // Object passed to the function did not validate.
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/reL2g/